Cannot resolve class or package 'dialect'
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maksimov.spring.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_course_mvc_hibernate_aop</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring_course_mvc_hibernate_aop Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTE-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring_course_mvc_hibernate_aop</finalName>
  </build>
</project>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.maksimov.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="bestuser" />
        <property name="password" value="bestuser" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.maksimov.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


</beans>

I've just started writing in Java and encountered this error. Could it potentially hinder my progress, or is it a bug? I've tried switching between MYSQLDialect, MySQL8Dialect, and MySQL57Dialect, but it hasn't helped. I've already specified all the necessary dependencies in the pom.xml file.
I've already tried changing the name of this dialect, but it doesn't help. I've also tried reinstalling Hibernate

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I've already specified all the necessary dependencies in the pom.xml file well apparently you didn't. Add your pom.xml. Next to that don't post code (and XML is code) as images (or worse links to images), instead include the code as text with proper code tags.
